# Word/Doc/Pdf file to csv file format

Tags: php, mysql, csv, type-conversion

I'm developing a PHP project i just want to know that is it possible to convert a doc/pdf file into csv file format then i would be able to import it to database (mysql).

I've tried every tutorial but failed to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

You may use the source code samples below to extract data from PDF to CSV in PHP using Cloud API (low level).

**Code Sample (PDF to CSV):**

```
            <?php
            require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

            // Configure API key authorization: api_key
            Bytescout\Client\API\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('x-api-key', 'YOUR_API_KEY');
            // Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
            // Bytescout\Client\API\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKeyPrefix('x-api-key', 'Bearer');

            $api_instance = new Swagger\Client\Api\DefaultApi();
            $pages = pages_example; // String | Comma-separated list of page indices (or ranges) to process. Leave empty for all pages. Example: '0,2-5,7-'.
            $name = name_example; // String | File name for generated result.
            $url = url_example; // String | URL of the source PDF file.

            try {
                $result = $api_instance->pdfConvertToCsvPost($pages, $name, $url);
                print_r($result);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Exception when calling DefaultApi->pdfConvertToCsvPost: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
            }
            ?>
```